# Deselect single item on click in VBA userform listbox control

Tags: vba, listbox, userform

can anybody point me in the right direction to achieve this?

VBA - UserForm - ListBox Control (single selection):

Usually, if you click on listboxe's item, then you select it. If you click on the same item again, you just select it again.

I would like to make the second click deselect the item, instead.

The listbox is programmatically created.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you,

Comment: Thank you marc_s for your corrections! I'm going to read the hints for a good questions.

Comment: What are you doing this in? (Excel, Access, etc?)  If Excel, I'm not sure it's possible because it won't even fire the OnClick event if you click on an already selected item.  Should be possible with Access though.

Comment: Actually, i'm doing it in a Visio document and i think it could be like you say for Excel. I red somewhere that a click in the ListBox doesn't fire an OnClick event. By the way, it was concerning multiselection ListBox. And i'm wondering...what event does it fire ? Perhaps, Something like OnChange?

Comment: In Excel, the `MouseDown` event fires.  But if you try to de-select an item, that will subsequently fire the `_Change` event...